# error when creating an new channel 'BAD_REQUEST -- error authorizing update: error validating DeltaSet'

Tags: hyperledger-fabric, hyperledger

I try to create [first-network](https://hyperledger-fabric.readthedocs.io/en/release-1.1/build_network.html) manually instead of using byfn.sh script, and when I try to create channel inside cli container.

```
peer channel create -o orderer.example.com:7050 -c mychannel -f ./channel-artifacts/channel.tx --tls true --cafile /opt/gopath/src/github.com/hyperledger/fabric/peer/crypto/ordererOrganizations/example.com/orderers/orderer.example.com/msp/tlscacerts/tlsca.example.com-cert.pem
```

I get this error:

```
Error: got unexpected status: BAD_REQUEST -- error authorizing update: error validating DeltaSet: policy for [Group]  /Channel/Application not satisfied: Failed to reach implicit threshold of 1 sub-policies, required 1 remaining
```

and this error from orderer:

```
ERRO 008 Principal deserialization failure (the supplied identity is not valid: x509: certificate signed by unknown authority (possibly because of "x509: ECDSA verification failure" while trying to verify candidate authority certificate "ca.org1.example.com")) for identity
```

*note:*

it's work fine if I use byfn.sh script

I found this

[peer channel creation fails in Hyperledger Fabric](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45726536/peer-channel-creation-fails-in-hyperledger-fabric),

[hyperledger fabric first_network example create channel got BAD_REQUEST](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48626108/hyperledger-fabric-first-network-example-create-channel-got-bad-request),

[FABRIC returns Error: Got unexpected status: BAD_REQUEST](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45707982/fabric-returns-error-got-unexpected-status-bad-request) questions

**but I still don't know how I can fix this error?**

**os host:** ubuntu 16:04

**hyperledger fabric version:** x86_64-1.1.0

Comment: Did you have any luck with this one?
I have the same issue, but my network is a bit different from the sample one.

Answer (score 3):

If you're still having this error, you might have already tried to start the network, and then started over.  You'll need to delete both the old docker containers and their volumes - they might try to be reused, and then old cert data will be used, leading to the `unknown authority` error.

Here are all the reset commands you'll want to use for the byfn.sh or similar script:

```
# STOP AND DELETE THE DOCKER CONTAINERS
docker ps -aq | xargs -n 1 docker stop
docker ps -aq | xargs -n 1 docker rm -v

# DELETE THE OLD DOCKER VOLUMES
docker volume prune

# DELETE OLD DOCKER NETWORKS (OPTIONAL: seems to restart fine without)
docker network prune

# DELETE SCRIPT-CREATED FILES
rm -rf channel-artifacts/*.block channel-artifacts/*.tx crypto-config
rm -f docker-compose-e2e.yaml

# VERIFY RESULTS
docker ps -a
docker volume ls
ls -l
```

Answer (score 0):

Try doing byfn down before starting manual steps. I think previous volumes are not cleared.